# Where is the source code of RippleDrawable? (Android L)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I am looking for the source code of RippleDrawable which is mentioned here https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#touch

and indeed it must exits because it is used in Android L for the ripple animation.

But, maybe it's my fault, I am not able to find it...

Thanks for any help.

This is what I found unzipping `android.jar` :-(((

```
public class RippleDrawable extends LayerDrawable
{
public RippleDrawable(Drawable content, Drawable mask)
{
super((Drawable[])null); throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setAlpha(int alpha) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public int getOpacity() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public boolean isStateful() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setColor(ColorStateList color) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void inflate(Resources r, XmlPullParser parser, AttributeSet attrs,   Resources.Theme theme) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException { throw new   RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public boolean setDrawableByLayerId(int id, Drawable drawable) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setPaddingMode(int mode) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void applyTheme(Resources.Theme t) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public boolean canApplyTheme() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setHotspot(float x, float y) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void setHotspotBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public void draw(Canvas canvas) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public Rect getDirtyBounds() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); } 
public Drawable.ConstantState getConstantState() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");        }

}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the Android L source codes via Android SDK Manager, zip up (with 7-zip for example) the Android L directory on your PC, then search within the zipped file for the `RippleDrawable` class? Just wondering...

Comment: @ChuongPham I did that, please see my edit

Comment: Okay, that clears it up now. Yes, the `RippleDrawable` class is exported to `android.jar`, but there's no corresponding documentation for it in the source codes of `Android L`. However, when I searched for [RippleDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#q=RippleDrawable), there's no indication of a page that documents the usage of this class. I guess either Google missed something, or since Android L is still in Preview mode that they do not provide formal documentation for it - in source and/or online at http://http://developer.android.com/.

Comment: @ChuongPham Hi Chuong, you are correct, but wen you say Yes, the `RippleDrawable class is exported to android.jar` what I get looking into the .jar is what you see in my question, seems to be totally unimplemented...and this makes no sense to me :-(

Comment: The `android.jar` is only for testing purposes. What installed in the firmware on a given Android device, is quite different. Meike's answer below explained it better than I can.

Comment: As of today, there's no Android device here in Australia with Android L installed on it - so I can't pull the ROM and check it for you. Don't know if it's available in other parts of the world, though. ;)

Comment: @ChuongPham there are a couple of ROMs made available by Google to be flashed on Nexus devices if you are interested :-)

Comment: I don't have a Nexus device handy. On the other hand, extracting components from a standalone ROM (not installed on a device) is quite an involved process - one I'm still familiarise with. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand how this works, you need to separate, in your head, the build and run environments.

In order to build you program you need only build against *definitions* of the Android API.  The android.jar that Google ships contains only stubs that define the API.  There are, for instance, many public methods in the API libraries that are marked with an "@hide" annotation.  Those methods are not put into android.jar at all.  Also, as you've noticed, the bodies of most of the methods just throw runtime exceptions.

The android.jar file is not part of your application.  At run time, your application binds against a real Android library, installed on the phone.  It includes actual implementations of the various API methods.

The code available at runtime, is found in the [AOSP](https://source.android.com/) project.

Unfortunately, Google has not dropped the L code, yet.  Short of pulling the the android library from a L-enabled device, and de-compiling that, there is no way to see the code for `RippleDrawable`

Bummer!